# Camunda REST API - Message is updating process variables

Tags: business-process-management, camunda

I want to know if the **POST /message function** of the **Camunda REST API** is updating process instance variables or does I have to update variables using the Update/Delete Process Variable function before sending a message ?

**Camunda REST API :**

- **Message reference** : http://docs.camunda.org/latest/api-references/rest/#message-deliver-a-message
- **Update/Delete Process Variable reference** : http://docs.camunda.org/latest/api-references/rest/#process-instance-updatedelete-process-variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the answer : The **Message function** is correctly updating the process instance variables.